Fuzzy-Sort Implementation and Analysis
I'm interested in solving Problem 7-7 from CLRS:

7-7 Fuzzy sorting of intervals
Consider a sorting problem in which you do not know the numbers exactly. Instead, for each number, you know an interval on the real line to which it belongs. That is, you are given $n$ closed intervals of the form $[a_i,b_i]$, where $a_i \leq b_i$. The goal is to fuzzy-sort these intervals: to produce a permutation $\langle i_1, i_2,\dots,i_n\rangle$ of the intervals such that for $j = 1,2,\dots,n$, there exist $c_j \in [a_{i_i}, b_{i_j}]$, satisfying $c_1 \leq c_2 \leq \cdots \leq c_n$.
a. Design a randomized algorithm for fuzzy-sorting $n$ intervals. Your algorithm should have the general structure of an algorithm that quicksorts the left end-points (the $a_i$ values), but it should take advantage of overlapping intervals to improve the running time. (As the intervals overlap more and more, the problem of fuzzy-sorting the intervals becomes progressively easier. Your algorithm should take advantage of such overlapping, the the extent that it exists.)
b. Argue that your algorithm runs in $\Theta (n \lg n)$ expected time in general, but runs in $\Theta(n)$ expected time when all of the intervals overlap (i.e., when there exists a value $x$ such that $x \in [a_i, b_i]$ for all $i$). Your algorithm should not be checking for this case explicitly, but rather, its performance should naturally improve as the amount of overlap increases.

My attempt:
a.
I've had a look at the implementation of quicksort in the text, and designed analogous functions. The key difference is that PARTITION returns two indices, where the set of intervals indexed in that range (including the pivot interval) have a non-empty intersection.
FUZZY-SORT(A, p, r)
    if p < r
        q, t = RANDOMIZED-PARTITION(A, p, r)
        FUZZY-SORT(A, p, q - 1)
        FUZZY-SORT(A, t + 1, r)


RANDOMIZED-PARTITION(A, p, r)
    i = RANDOM(p, r)
    exchange A[r] with A[i]
    return PARTITION(A, p, r)    


PARTITION(A, p, r)
    x = A[r]
    I_a = x.a
    I_b = x.b
    q = p - 1
    dt = 0
    for j = p to r - 1
        // if the current interval is entirely to the left of the running intersection
        if A[j].b < I_a
            exchange A[j] with A[q + dt + 1]
            exchange A[q + dt + 1] with A[q + 1]
            q = q + 1
        // if the current interval intersects the running intersection, include it
        elif max(I_a, A[j].a) <= min(I_b, A[j].b)
            dt = dt + 1
            I_a = max(I_a, A[j].a)
            I_b = min(I_b, A[j].b)
            exchange A[j] with A[q + dt]
        dt = dt + 1
        exchange A[r] with A[q + dt]
    return q + 1, q + dt     


b. I am unclear about the meaning of "in general" here. I suspect some information on the distribution of the intervals is missing, especially given the problem states linear complexity is possible in some cases.

In summary I would like help with the following:

Is my implementation of FUZZY-SORT "correct" as far as the problem is concerned? If it fails to meet some of the requirements, I would appreciate advice on how to fix that.
For part b, I understand how linear complexity arises when all intervals share a value. There is essentially one linear pass and the array gets sorted. I am not at all clear on proving $\Theta(n \lg n)$ in the general case, nor what the "general case" actually is. I doubt generating the intervals' endpoints randomly via $Uniform[-N,N]$ and then taking $N \to +\infty$ is what the authors meant...

